# Modular exponentiation fails for large mod in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, cryptography, exponentiation, modular-arithmetic

This is the code I'm using for calculating `(n^p)%mod`. Unfortunately, it fails for large values of `mod` (in my case `mod = 10000000000ULL`) when I call it from `main()` method. Any idea; why?

```
ull powMod(ull n, ull p, ull mod) {
    ull ans = 1;
    n = n%mod;
    while(p) {
        if(p%2 == 1) {
            ans = (ans*n)%mod;
        }
        n = (n*n)%mod;
        p /= 2;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Here, `ull` is a typedef for `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Use a multi-precision library like GMP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do it in C++. As others pointed out you cannot do it *directly*. Using a little drop of number theory it is possible to decompose the problem into two manageable sub problems.

First consider that `10^10 = 2^10 * 5^10`. Both factors are coprime, so you can use the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to find the power modulo `10^10` using the powers modulo `2^10` and modulo `5^10`.

Note that in the following code the *magic* values `u2` and `u5` were found using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). You don't need to program this algorithm yourself because these values are constants. I use [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) and its [gcdex](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_14.html#gcdex) function, to compute them.

Here is the modified version:

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;

ull const M  = 10000000000ull;

ull pow_mod10_10(ull n, ull p) {
  ull const m2 = 1024;    // 2^10
  ull const m5 = 9765625; // 5^10
  ull const M2 = 9765625; // 5^10 = M / m2
  ull const M5 = 1024;    // 2^10 = M / m5
  ull const u2 = 841;     // u2*M2 = 1 mod m2
  ull const u5 = 1745224; // u5*M5 = 1 mod m5

  ull b2 = 1;
  ull b5 = 1;
  ull n2 = n % m2;
  ull n5 = n % m5;

  while(p) {
    if(p%2 == 1) {
      b2 = (b2*n2)%m2;
      b5 = (b5*n5)%m5;
    }
    n2 = (n2*n2)%m2;
    n5 = (n5*n5)%m5;
    p /= 2;
  }

  ull np = (((b2*u2)%M)*M2)%M;
  np    += (((b5*u5)%M)*M5)%M;
  np    %= M;
  return np;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Kudos to your approach.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't avoid it.

If `mod` is `10000000000ULL`, in `(a*b)%c` in your program, both `a` and `b` are smaller than mod so we treat them as `9999999999ULL`, `a*b` will be `99999999980000000001`, but `unsigned long long` can only express `2^64-1=18446744073709551615 < 99999999980000000001` so your method will be overflow.

Comment: my n and p, are both less than 2*10^6. So, the product should never be a problem I guess. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: `ans = (ans*n)%mod;` and `n = (n*n)%mod;`, `n` and `ans` may be larger than 2*10^6

Comment: Does this mean that Project Euler #48 on HackerRank (https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler048) cannot be solved in C++?

Comment: @saint1729 You can implement BigInteger yourself in C++, but I suggest to  use python

Comment: @saint1729 You don't need to implement BigInteger for this specific scenario. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible issues here seems to be that when you do `(a*b)%c`, the `a*b` part itself could overflow, resulting in a wrong answer. One way to work around that is to use the identity that

```
(a*b)%c
```

is equivalent to

```
(a%c * b%c)%c
```

This will prevent overflows in the intermediate multiplications as well.

Comment: I there. I tried it. In my case a*b <= 4*10^12 < 2^64-1 and so that is not giving me any advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Your code line

```
 n = (n*n)%mod;
```

is repeatedly executed.
As long as n is smaller than mod, this will potentially result in evaluating (mod-1)*(mod-1) at some point in time.

On input n may not be so large, but the mentioned line of code increases n in the loop.